# How to prevent grid items from overlapping with unbroken text

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';

import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
//import Grid from '@mui/material/Unstable_Grid2'; // Grid version 2
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Container fixed>
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={8} md={8}>
          <p>
            !!ldsfjsdlkfjklsdsdjflksdfjldskfjdlskfjdslkfjdslkfjsdlkfdsfjlkdsjfkldsjflksdfjsdlkfjlkjdsflksdjfklsdjflkdsfjlksdfjlsdkfldsjflkdsjlkffjdslkfjsdlkfdsfjlkdsjfkldsjflksdfjsdlkfjlk
          </p>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4} md={4}>
          <p>
            ldsfjsdlkfjklsdsdjflksdfjldskfjdlskfjdslkfjdslkfjsdlkfdsfjlkdsjfkldsjflksdfjsdlkfjljdsflksdjfklsdjflkdsfjlksdfjlsdkfldsjflkdsjlkffjdslkfjsdlkfdsfjlkdsjfkldsjflksdfjsdlkfjlk
          </p>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

---

[image]

---

I want to not overlap gird items in 'xs'.
I think text in a p tag should be split into newlines.

I tried new Grid (version2) component also. but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by giving your `<p>` element with CSS style of

```css
word-wrap: break-word;
```

See it in action https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-meitner-54z59k?file=/src/App.tsx